# How to import line-awesome framework into vue.js app?

Tags: html, vue.js, font-awesome

I can't import line-awesome framework and use its icons in vue.js application.

I have tried to add the CDN link in my html file as mentioned [here](https://icons8.com/articles/line-awesome/).

When adding it, and trying to use its icons like

```
 <i class="la la-home"></i>
```

the webpage showing nothing, but when using

```
 <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
```

instead, the webpage show the font-awesome home icon, however I am still importing the CDN of line-awesome.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is very unclear as you figured out. There are actually two CDN-links on the [how-to page](https://icons8.com/line-awesome/howto), even if they look identical.

The first CDN-link at time of writing is actually just a drop-in for FontAwesome and does not define any styling with the `.la`-prefix. To use that, you need to define your icons as found in the FontAwesome documentation. Things should work just fine if you use `<i class="fa fa-home"></i>` like you figured out.

The second CDN-link defines all the `.la`-styling and none of the `.fa`-styling. If you include that link, you can actually use the documentation to include their icons.

Comment: but it works for regular html and css page and when it comes to vue webpage this issue start to appear

Comment: Not true, It's because it has different styles, one is which replaces your current icons that uses font-awesome with line-awesome icons
The other style uses It's own classes which then .la and .la-* will work as expected if you import the right one. *Edit:*
I just looked at the date, so I guess maybe they did have this problem back then, but It's fixed now, please consider updating your answer if so.

Comment: @Javad The documentation links https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/font-awesome-line-awesome/css/all.min.css as the CDN. Open the file and search for `.la`. No classes are defined with that prefix.

Comment: I've made an [issue](https://github.com/icons8/line-awesome/issues/35) on Github to improve the documentation